# Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.12:run (default-cli) on project : Application finished with exit code: 1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin

I have a SpringBoot application with the following version. I plan to update spring-boot-starter-parent 2.1.3-RELEASE to 2.5.12.

Below are the upgraded versions,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"\>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>partnerProfileProductsBatch</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.3.9</maven>
    </prerequisites>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.12</version>
    </parent>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone-repo</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.1.212</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>3.6.0</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.12</version>
            </plugin>
            
            <!-- Make this jar executable -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>aws/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>awsqa/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>dev/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>local/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>preprod/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>prod/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>sandbox/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>qav2/**</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>org.nwea.partnerprofile.Application</mainClass>
                    <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    
            <!-- Copy project dependency -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <!-- exclude junit, we need runtime dependency only -->
                      <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>copy-resources</id>
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/products_conf</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                      <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                          <include>**/*.properties</include>
                          <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                      </resource>
                    </resources>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    
    </build>

\`
```

I have upgraded all the dependencies, but I was getting below error when running the application, however, the build was a success.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.528 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-01-18T20:08:22+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.12:run (default-cli) on project: Applic
ation finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.12:run (default-cli
) on project partnerProfileProductsBatch: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm (RunMojo.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:286)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:251)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I tried searching for the error messages over the internet, however, I couldn't figure out any solution.

I need suggestions to troubleshoot the issue in order to identify the solution.

I am trying to upgrade the spring beans version v5.1.5.RELEASE to v5.3.18.

Comment: You have messed up your whole setup because several versions of Spring Boot / Spring mixed up... Spring Boot parent 2.5.12 and deps with spring boot version 3.0.1 etc. Clean up your app... that will never work..configured maven-dependency-plugin etc.. Ah..also configured access to milestone repository (is not allowed anymore since 2020???) ... apart from that not needed...

Comment: @Khmarbaise, Thanks for the information. Do you have any idea which maven plugin i.e org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin version supports for Spring Boot v2.5.12, Spring beans v5.3.18

Comment: If you like to use a particular spring boot version you have to use the same spring-boot-maven-plugin version... The spring version is a different question. You should check the dependencies in spring-boot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to mention version number for spring-boot-starter-* dependencies and plugins if you are using spring-boot-starter parent in pom.xml. Spring boot framework automatically provide compatible versions of dependencies/plugins based on Spring Boot version mentioned in pom.xml (2.5.12 in your case)

So I will suggest to remove version number for spring-boot-maven-plugin and build your project again

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with your `pom.xml`, you are trying to outsmart the Spring Boot starters with dependency management as well as the building of the jar. Or in other words your `pom.xml` is overly complex and can (and should) be greatly simplified.

1. You are mixing Spring Boot 2.5.12 and 3.0.1 dependencies that isn't going to work, remove the versions from the starters.
2. You included some 6.0.3 version of `spring-context-support` that isn't going to work as that is for Spring Boot 3.
3. You are including other dependencies with versions that are managed by Spring Boot (like `spring-batch-test` and others).
4. The Spring Boot plugin already creates an executable jar no need to add the jar plugin, dependency plugin etc.
5. `spring-boot-starter-logging` isn't needed
6. HikariCP isn't needed as that is already the default and pulled in by `spring-boot-starter-jpa`.
7. `spring-boot-test-autoconfigure` is already part of `spring-boot-starter-test`.
8. Your pre-requisits conflict with your enforcer-plugin
9. `maven-compiler-plugin` is defined by the Spring Boot starter parent and uses the `java.version` property
10. You had a link to the milestone repository but didn't include any milestones (removed it).

Below is the cleaned up `pom.xml`. I'm also not sure if you need the `maven-resources-plugin` as those properties and XML files are already in the build jar.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"\>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>partnerProfileProductsBatch</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
      
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.12</version>
    </parent>
       
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC Drivers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-maven</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <version>3.6.0</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <generateBackupPoms>false</generateBackupPoms>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>copy-resources</id>
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/products_conf</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                      <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                          <include>**/*.properties</include>
                          <include>**/*.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                      </resource>
                    </resources>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    
    </build>
</project>
```

Some final thoughts

- I don't think you should be using `org.springframework` as the `groupId` but rather your own.
- You have an awful lot of JDBC drivers in there including 2 in-memory ones, which can be troublesome in detecting which driver to use. I also think that the H2 version supplied isn't supported by this version of Spring Boot (or hibernate).
- I would suggest upgrading to 2.7.7 instead of 2.5.12 to have at least a supported version as 2.5.x isn't a supported version range anymore.

Comment: The issue got resolved, I just removed all the maven plugins version which were mentioned,  those maven plugin-compatible versions automatically have been taken from the Spring boot framework.

Comment: I found one issue regarding no bean of the type found, so have added spring batch dependency after running the mvn clean install command, now the application running as expected. Thanks for the valuable information.